# typedef structs declared inside class or outside?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm creating a class called ImageLoader that will be used to load various image formats.  For various image formats there are certain structs used.  For example with bmp files you have a BITMAPFILEHEADER struct and two others.

What I want to know is, when I'm putting my class definition in the header file, do I make the struct typedefs part of the class definition, or should they be separate, outside the class definition?

I'm not sure because if I was just declaring a struct variable, that would obviously happen in the class, but because I'm defining a type, I'm not sure if it's considered good design to define a type inside a class.

Comment: Why are you using typedef on structs at all in C++?  You can just use the name of the struct.

Comment: Cause I'm used to C and old habits die hard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My general rule is that if it will only be used in conjunction with that class, then declare it inside (it implies ownership); otherwise declare it separately.

Answer (score 3):

You get better encapsulation if you leave out everything from the header that you possibly can. Even if some methods of your class need parameters or return types of the struct, you might get away with a forward declaration.

The only time you *need* to put it in the header is when it's part of the public interface.

As to whether it goes in the class or not, consider whether it's useful on its own or if it is totally subservient to the class. If it can stand alone it should probably go in its own header.

Answer (score 3):

I would not say that declaring a type in a class is an indicator of bad design. Assuming that your mention of "design" means something along the lines of "readability", I would be a stickler for consistency and insist that the same relationships be expressed in the same way.

Otherwise, you are not going to be struck down by a divine wrath for nesting types (Considering SGI is not a smoldering crater). This is pretty context-centric, so there are no hard and fast rules outside of what you define based on your requirements.

If client accessibility is not an issue, I declare most everything in an appropriate scope in headers and just document what my code means. Again, this is if I do not have strict usage/readability guidelines to enforce. I'd go with Mark's suggestion if I did.

Two cents: You could try enumerating image types and using one public struct for config data so that you could justify pulling everything else behind closed doors.

Answer (score 1):

[BITMAPFILEHEADER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183374%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a structure defined in the Win32 Platform SDK. I'm not sure I've understood your request about it and your class...

In general, if you are defining structures that are not exposed to the client of your class, I'd define them in the private part of your class, or in a sub-namespace `Details` in your header file, e.g.:

```
namespace YourCoolLibrary
{
  namespace Details
  {
    struct SomeInternalStructure
    {
      ...
    };

  } // namespace Details


  class YourCoolClass
  {
    ...
  private:
    Details::SomeInternalStructure m_something;
  };

} // namespace YourCoolLibrary
```

Comment: Yeah, I know it exists in win32, but I'm going to be porting this over to non windows platforms. I'm remaking the struct so using it would be the same as how it's used in win32.

Answer (score 1):

There are even many more choices. If you put it in the class you have to choose if it's public, protected, or private making the class definition visible for every user of the class, only derived classes or no other classes.

If you do not need the details of the class definition I'd put only forward declarations into ImageLoader to keep it simpler. The full definition of the inner class then goes into the implementation file.

My rule of thumb is to make names as local as possible, so if I use it accidentally at the wrong place the compiler will complain.

Answer (score 0):

If the `typedef` logically belongs into the class you are creating, put it inside; if it would make sense on a global level, leave it outside.